"Any CPU" .NET 8 WinForms Executable on 32-bit Windows OS
Our .NET 8 WinForms application is compiled targeting "Any CPU", but will not run on a 32-bit OS.
It's my understanding that this means the application will run as a 32-bit process on a 32-bit OS and as a 64-bit process on a 64-bit OS.
It will run as a 64-bit process on a 64-bit OS, but on a 32-bit OS we get a generic "This app can't run on your PC" message.
If we compile targeting x86, then the same application will run fine on the same 32-bit OS.
There are no dependencies coming into play, I can replicate the behavior with a boiler-plate WinForms app.
What am I missing? Am I misinterpreting what "Any CPU" does?

FWIW, I don't believe that you are. Which version of the O/S is the 32-bit box running?

It is running Windows 10 Pro, Version 22H2, OS Build 19045.4529

It is only truly "any cpu" if you start your app with dotnet.exe.  The .exe file you get after building your project is the apphost.  Its job is to load and initialize the CLR so it can run the .dll file your project generates.  An unmanaged program, x64 when targeting AnyCPU.
